# Asymptotic equivalent of $\sum_{k=1}^n a^k k^{-1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, asymptotics

I encountered recently the following partial sum  $\sum_{k=1}^n a^k k^{-1/2}$ with $a$ a constant approximately equal to $2.955$.

I was wondering if there were any clever way to find an asymptotic to this partial sum. I recognized the partial sum of a (divergent) polylogarithm but was not able to find any further literature on this question.

Any help would be welcome !

Comment: $$S(a)=\sum_{k=1}^n a^k k^{-1/2}=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{a^{n-l}}{\sqrt{n-l}}=\frac{a^n}{\sqrt n}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac ln\right)^{-1/2}a^{-l}=\frac{a^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1+\frac an\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^{-1/2}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}a^{-l}$$

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thanks. Would you be so kind to detail how, in your first comment, you manage to out from the sum $(1-l/n)^{-1/2}$, and where this $\partial/\partial a$ comes from ? Thank you!

Comment: Slight correction
$$S(a)\sim\frac{a^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1+\frac an\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^{-1/2}\sum_{l=0}^\infty a^{-l}=\frac{a^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1+\frac an\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^{-1/2}\frac a{a-1}$$
$$=\frac{a^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac a{2n}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}+\frac {3}{8n^2}\big(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\big)^2-...\right)^{-1/2}\frac a{a-1}=\frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1}\frac1{\sqrt n}\left(1+\frac1{2(a-1)}\frac1n+O\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)\right)$$

Comment: $$-l\,a^{-l}=a\frac{\partial }{\partial a}a^{-l}; l^2\,a^{-l}=(a\frac{\partial }{\partial a})^2a^{-l}, etc.$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I must be missing something, I don't understand how does the term $\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^{-1/2}$ appear. Is this some kind of half-derivative or something ? Maybe it is some advanced calculus that I am not aware of. Any clarification/reference would be very appreciated.

Comment: This is an operational form, which should be understood as $(1+\frac ln)^{-1/2}$ decomposition:
$$(1-\frac ln)^{-1/2}a^{-l}=\left(1+\frac12\frac ln+\frac38\frac{l^2}{n^2}+...\right)a^{-l}$$
$$=\left(1-\frac 1{2n}(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})+\frac38\frac1{n^2}(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})+...\right)a^{-l}$$
$$(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})a^{-l}=-l\,a^{-l};\,(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})a^{-l}=(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})\Big(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a}a^{-l}\Big)=(a\frac{\partial}{\partial a})(-l\,a^{-l})=l^2a^{-l}$$
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all, there is a exact result. For $a>1$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {a^k}{\sqrt k}=\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}(a)-a^{n+1} \Phi
   \left(a,\frac{1}{2},n+1\right)$$ where $\Phi(.)$ is  the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$S_n=A_0+ a^n \,\frac {A_1}{ n^\frac 12}+ a^n \,\frac {A_2}{ n^\frac 32}+\cdots$$
$$A_0=E_{\frac{1}{2}}(-\log (a)) + a A_3$$
$$A_1=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{12}-\frac{x^3}{720}+\frac{x^5}{30240}-\frac{x^7}{1209600}+\frac{x^9}{47900160}$$
$$A_2=\frac{1}{2 x^2}-\frac{1}{24}+\frac{x^2}{480}-\frac{x^4}{12096}+\frac{x^6}{345600}-\frac{x^8}{10644480}$$

For this level of expansion
$$A_3=\frac{2125613}{3932160}-\frac{482719 x}{5898240}-\frac{6103 x^2}{5160960}+\frac{2699 x^3}{2580480}+\frac{1807
   x^4}{17031168}-\frac{7943
   x^5}{212889600}+\frac{x^6}{2534400}+\frac{x^7}{3801600}+\frac{x^8}{10644480}-\frac{x^9}{47900160}$$ where $\color{red}{x=\log(a)}$.

For $a=3$ and $n=10^4$, this gives
$\color{red}{2.4470864}56\color{red}{\times 10^{4769}}$ while the exact value is
$\color{red}{2.447086463}\color{red}{\times 10^{4769}}$

@Svyatoslav's much simpler formula

$$\frac{a^{n+1}}{a-1}\frac1{\sqrt n}\left(1+\frac1{2(a-1)}\frac1n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$ would give for the same case $\color{red}{2.4470864}54\color{red}{\times 10^{4769}}$